# DATEDIFF does not return an integer value T-SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime, sql-server-2012

I am trying to see if how much time it took to insert some values into a table in SQL Server 2012.

This how I am trying to do:

```
DECLARE @starttime DATETIME
DECLARE @timetook DATETIME

CREATE TABLE MyTable (id INT, name CHAR(10));

SET @starttime = SYSDATETIME()

INSERT INTO MyTable (id, name) 
VALUES (1, 'Bob'), (2, 'Peter'), (3, 'Joe'),
       (4, 'Boby'), (5, 'Peters'), (6, 'Joey'),
       (7, 'Bobs'), (8, 'Petery'), (9, 'Joes');

SET @timetook = DATEDIFF(ss, @starttime, SYSDATETIME())

SELECT @timetook
```

This returns `1900-01-01 00:00:00.000`. According to the `datediff` [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/datediff-transact-sql), it should be `00:00:00.000` or an integer value. Since I am taking the seconds, I should get the number in seconds. (For this example it should be 0 but without 1900-01-01)

What am I missing here? Any suggestion would be appreciated.

Comment: Your timetook variable is a datetime so the representation is in datetime. Try as int.

Comment: should post that as an answer @JacobH

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Declaring @timetook as datetime will give you a datetimeresult. And the datetime = 0 is specifically `1900-01-01 00:00:00.000`.

```
declare @starttime datetime
declare @timetook int --Issue was this declaration as datetime

CREATE TABLE MyTable (id int, name char(10));

set @starttime = SYSDATETIME()

INSERT INTO MyTable (id, name) VALUES (1, 'Bob'), (2, 'Peter'), (3, 'Joe'),
                                      (4, 'Boby'), (5, 'Peters'), (6, 'Joey'),
                                      (7, 'Bobs'), (8, 'Petery'), (9, 'Joes');
set @timetook = DATEDIFF(ss, @starttime, SYSDATETIME())

select @timetook
```

By declaring @timetook as int, you will get the result you are looking for: `0`